# Split strings into individual charaters, count number of times each character occurs then combine into single df/matrix

Tags: r

I have a list of strings where I want to count how many times each character occurs in them and produce a single dataframe or matrix as an output.
I can do it for each individual string separately but struggling with combining the answer into a single output.

```
###Data
strings <- c("ba", "uv", "bg", "vuabv", "nabvnmnm")

### Split into single characters
single_chars <- str_split(strings, "")
```

Desired Output

```
strings  |a|b|u|v|g|n|m
ba       |1|1|0|0|0|0|0
uv       |0|0|1|1|0|0|0
bg       |0|1|0|0|1|0|0
vuabv    |1|1|1|2|0|0|0
nabvnmnm |1|1|0|1|0|3|2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `dplyr`, `tibble`, `purrr` and `stringr` option could be:

```
bind_cols(tibble(strings),
          map_dfc(.x = unique(unlist(str_split(strings, boundary("character")))),
                  ~ tibble(!!.x := str_count(strings, .x))))

  strings      b     a     u     v     g     n     m
  <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 ba           1     1     0     0     0     0     0
2 uv           0     0     1     1     0     0     0
3 bg           1     0     0     0     1     0     0
4 vuabv        1     1     1     2     0     0     0
5 nabvnmnm     1     1     0     1     0     3     2
```

Comment: Perfect, was hoping for a way that didn't involve multiple for loops. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `factor` + `table`

```
cbind(
  strings,
  as.data.frame(
    do.call(
      rbind,
      lapply(
        lst <- strsplit(strings, ""),
        function(x) table(factor(x, levels = unique(sort(unlist(lst)))))
      )
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
   strings a b g m n u v
1       ba 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
2       uv 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
3       bg 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
4    vuabv 1 1 0 0 0 1 2
5 nabvnmnm 1 1 0 2 3 0 1
```